# Scheduling of Process(s) waiting for Semaphore

Tags: c++, operating-system, kernel, mutex, semaphore

It is always said when the count of a semaphore is 0, the process requesting the semaphore are blocked and added to a wait queue.
When some process releases the semaphore, and count increases from 0->1, a blocking process is activated. This can be any process, randomly picked from the blocked processes.

Now my question is:
If they are added to a queue, why is the activation of blocking processes NOT in FIFO order? I think it would be easy to pick next process from the queue rather than picking up a process at random and granting it the semaphore. If there is some idea behind this random logic, please explain. Also, how does the kernel select a process at random from queue? **getting a random process that too from queue is something complex as far as a queue data structure is concerned**.
tags: **various OSes** as each have a **kernel** usually written in **C++** and **mutex** shares similar concept

Comment: You seem to be using "Q" and "Queue" interchangeably. Maybe that's the source of your confusion.

Answer (score 2):

A FIFO is the simplest data structure for the waiting list in a system
that doesn't support priorities, but it's not the absolute answer
otherwise.  Depending on the scheduling algorithm chosen, different
threads might have different absolute priorities, or some sort of
decaying priority might be in effect, in which case, the OS might choose 
the thread which has had the least CPU time in some preceding interval.
Since such strategies are widely used (particularly the latter), the
usual rule is to consider that you don't know (although with absolute
priorities, it will be one of the threads with the highest priority).

Answer (score 2):

When a process is scheduled "at random", it's not that a process is randomly chosen; it's that the selection process is not predictable.

The algorithm used by Windows kernels is that there is a queue of threads (Windows schedules "threads", not "processes") waiting on a semaphore. When the semaphore is released, the kernel schedules the next thread waiting in the queue. However, scheduling the thread does not immediately make that thread start executing; it merely makes the thread able to execute by putting it in the queue of threads waiting to run. The thread will not actually run until a CPU has no threads of higher priority to execute.

While the thread is waiting in the scheduling queue, another thread that is actually executing may wait on the same semaphore. In a traditional queue system, that new thread would have to stop executing and go to the end of the queue waiting in line for that semaphore.

In recent Windows kernels, however, the new thread does not have to stop and wait for that semaphore. If the thread that has been assigned that semaphore is still sitting in the run queue, the semaphore may be reassigned to the old thread, causing the old thread to go back to waiting on the semaphore again.

The advantage of this is that the thread that was about to have to wait in the queue for the semaphore and then wait in the queue to run will not have to wait at all. The disadvantage is that you cannot predict which thread will actually get the semaphore next, and it's not fair so the thread waiting on the semaphore could potentially starve.

Answer (score 1):

It is not that it CAN'T be FIFO; in fact, I'd bet many implementations ARE, for just the reasons that you state.  The spec isn't that the process is chosen at random; it is that it isn't specified, so your program shouldn't rely on it being chosen in any particular way.  (It COULD be chosen at random; just because it isn't the fastest approach doesn't mean it can't be done.)

Comment: Thats what my concern is. If somebody writes a kernel, doing a random pickup, what motivation can be there behind his thinking and his strategy, Data Structure etc..  
Not sure of semaphore but yes, in case of mutex, the threads wakes up randomly. Both of them will share simlar logic i guess. So something i am missing.   
It makes me think that some process will keep on checking and then if it found semaphore val>0, it will get it and others will be blocked, which is just opposite to what the theory says and i am here to seek help of geeks here 8-)

Comment: It isn't that someone wrote a semaphore which uses rand() to pick the thread to release. That would be madness. It is that there is a bunch of stuff going on that you can't see which makes it look random. For example imagine the threads were released in FIFO order, but the quantum ended just before the ret that returns to your code and another bunch of threads run before you get rescheduled. That makes it look random, even though the kernel is still using a FIFO.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers here are great descriptions of the basic problem - especially around thread priorities and ready queues. Another thing to consider however is IO. I'm only talking about Windows here, since it is the only platform I know with any authority, but other kernels are likely to have similar issues.

On Windows, when an IO completes, something called a kernel-mode APC (Asynchronous Procedure Call) is queued against the thread which initiated the IO in order to complete it. If the thread happens to be waiting on a scheduler object (such as the semaphore in your example) then the thread is removed from the wait queue for that object which causes the (internal kernel mode) wait to complete with (something like) STATUS_ALERTED. Now, since these kernel-mode APCs are an implementation detail, and you can't see them from user mode, the kernel implementation of WaitForMultipleObjects restarts the wait at that point which causes your thread to get pushed to the back of the queue. From a kernel mode perspective, the queue is still in FIFO order, since the first caller of the underlying wait API is still at the head of the queue, however from your point of view, way up in user mode, you just got pushed to the back of the queue due to something you didn't see and quite possibly had no control over. This makes the queue order appear random from user mode. The implementation is still a simple FIFO, but because of IO it doesn't look like one from a higher level of abstraction.

I'm guessing a bit more here, but I would have thought that unix-like OSes have similar constraints around signal delivery and places where the kernel needs to hijack a process to run in its context.

Now this doesn't always happen, but the documentation has to be conservative and unless the order is explicitly guaranteed to be FIFO (which as described above - for windows at least - it can't be) then the ordering is described in the documentation as being "random" or "undocumented" or something because a random process controls it. It also gives the OS vendors lattitude to change the ordering at some later time.

Answer (score 0):

Process scheduling algorithms are very specific to system functionality and operating system design. It will be hard to give a good answer to this question. If I am on a general PC, I want something with good throughput and average wait/response time. If I am on a system where I know the priority of all my jobs and know I absolutely want all my high priority jobs to run first (and don't care about preemption/starvation), then I want a Priority algorithm.

As far as a random selection goes, the motivation could be for various reasons. One being an attempt at good throughput, etc. as mentioned above above. However, it would be non-deterministic (hypothetically) and impossible to prove. This property could be an exploitation of probability (random samples, etc.), but, again, the proofs could only be based on empirical data on whether this would really work.

Comment: Everything done in the machine would have to be pseudo-random. Like in a simple program `srand(time(NULL))`, an algorithm is used to generate a number based off the current time. You could use something as simple as that (i.e. a thread-safe rand() producing a number 0 - num_threads_in_queue) or develop another algorithm.